# iterations on a calculator

Tags: sequences-and-series

Ok, first off I am not a mathematician, so I apologize if terms are misused, I will try to get my questions across with plain English so I don't stumble on using a term that may mean something specific to a mathematician.

Starting with "iterations" (it may mean something specific - but I mean it in general)

For instance - here is the scenario hat made me want to do something I couldn't figure out how to do - but I am sure there is a way to express it in a formula to get my answer.

Proposition - Put a quarter a day in the jar - have $9125 in a year...

Clearly this assertion was wrong, and simple math (.25*365) tells anyone that you'll have $91.25 in a year.

But then I wanted to see what would happen in you started at .25 and "added a quarter to the last amount added every day...what would you get?

```
> day 1 = add .25 (total=.25) 
> day 2 = add .25 + .25 (total=.75) 
> day 3 =
> add .5 + .25 (total=1.5) 
> day 4 = add .75 + .25 (total=2.25) 
> etc... to 365 days
```

How would you express this on a calculator (normal generally available software calculator or spreadsheet)

Like wise (second question) - how would you figure doubling an amount for x iterations?

Thanks

Comment: The original can be phrased as a recursive sequence $a_0 = 0, a_n = a_{n-1}+0.25$ to which the closed form as you should clearly be able to see is $a_n = 0.25n$.  The second question you pose is a recursive sequence of the form $a_0 =0, a_n = a_{n-1}+0.25n$ to which the closed form is $\frac{1}{4}\times \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, that is a quarter of the $n$'th [triangle number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).  You would have $a_n = 16698.75$.  For information on how to solve this and other such things by hand, look up linear recurrence equations.

Comment: In mathmatics this is called  a "recursive definition" and it is define as $b_{n+1} = b_n + .25$ and our running total is $t_{n+1} = t_n + b_{n+1}$.  In computer programing it can be in the form of a function that calls itself.  function daily_add(n){if (n==0) return 0; else return daily_add(n-1) + .25;}

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_{n}$ denote the amount that you are adding to the jar on day $n$. So $$a_{1}=.25, a_{2}=.5, a_{3} = .75,..., a_{n}=.25n$$

Then the amount that you have in the jar at day $n$ is your starting amount, which in this case is $0$, plus all of the amounts you've added up to this point. That is, the amount you have at day $n$ is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}.25k=.25\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=.25\frac{k(k+1)}{2}=\frac{k(k+1)}{8}$$

Here I used the well-known identity
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You asked how to perform your calculation in a spreadsheet.  Here is one way to do it.  I am assuming you are using Excel or something similar.

1. Enter 0.25 in call A1.
2. Enter =A1+0.25 in call A2.
3. Enter =A1 in cell B1.
4. Enter =B1+A2 in cell B2.
5. Select and copy cells A2 and B2.
6. Paste into the rectangular region with upper left hand corner cell A3 and lower right-hand corner B365.

When you are done, column A will contain the amount to be added each day, and column B will contain the total amount in your bank on each day, so the total amount in your bank on day 365 will appear in cell B365.